# Stop propagation on custom event through callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to word it, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my-element', function(e) {
    var data = [{
        'event': e,
        'self': this
    }];

    // Trigger the override function first in case they need to stop prop
    $(document).trigger('override:something',dataa);

    // Would like to only trigger this default method if the event above is not set
    $(document).trigger('something',data);
});
```

Then on another page I have something to catch this event, like so:

```
$(document).on('override:something', function(e,data) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    data.e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // neither work
});
```

If I could stop all subsequent events like this that would be optimal, but I could also make it work if there were a way to check if custom events are set.

I could check whether `override:something` exists and if it does, do not execute the default `something` event afterwards.

I've tried setting removing specific callbacks like this, but it did not perform as expected and could get hard to manage.

```
var mycb = function() {
    alert('hi');
}
$(document).on('something', mycb);
// now to remove it
$(document).off('something', mycb); // does not remove the event
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually passing the data array in the triggered event?

Comment: One suggestion is look into using localStorage or sessionStorage to store some sort of page state data. A demo would help for this, not entirely clear what is going on

Comment: Yes sorry I just forgot to include `data` while typing it out. I have updated the question. I have an element that normally needs one function when it is clicked, but at certain times it needs other functions applied to it and the original one prevented.

Comment: I'm not sure of the execution order in jQuery. Could you verify with some logging that the event handler for `override:something` actually fires before the original event handler exits? Also try adding `e.stopPropagation()` and maybe even `e.preventDefault()` for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, but this solution seems to the only thing I've found to work for now. Still accepting alternate answers, though.

```
    var override = jQuery._data($(document)[0], 'events')['override:something'];

    $(document).trigger('override:something', data);

    if ( typeof override == typeof undefined )
        $(document).trigger('dashboard:friend', data);
```